# Keep data for node app when alive

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, require

I've node application and I need to keep data(as far the node app is alive) which will serve the user requests,(I dont want to calculate/parse it for every request so I do it once...) ,
when the node app is down I dont need this data anymore.

I found the following(which is working) but not sure is this is the best way to do so
and what is the drawback if any.

This is what I use which is working

```
require.cache.persist.myData = myData;
```

I use node with express

Comment: It sounds like your current method caches the data for all sessions/users  (Data stored per app instance).  If this data is related to the session (data stored per session instance), you might want to use session data.  I found this article, if it helps.  https://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/manage-session-using-node-js-express-4/

Comment: try node-cache for caching. I would use a proper database.https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache

Comment: Why not just save the data to a file after you have first parsed it. Use a local sessionID in the filename to keep it relevant to the app instance. Delete it when the app closes.

Comment: I use memcached for this stuff. What's great is the cache can be shared across instances of my app, and it will survive beyond an app restart.

Comment: If you just need a few things through the server's live time - just store them inside an Object. It's pretty simple and you **don't have** to use any kind of package. Just use a file, export one object and start putting things inside it :)

Answer (score 27):

There are many ways one can make data persistent, depending on what level of persistence you need. I'll outline a few approaches below.

---

## Application-level Persistence

For when you need data to remain available for **as long as the Node application is running**. If it stops or crashes, the data is lost. This is the easiest problem to solve, and I think the level that you're looking for in your application.

Anything that your Node program loads into memory will remain accessible until the program stops. So if your program starts off with the line

```
var myData = { ... };
```

then myData will remain in memory and accessible *from that file* for as long as the application does. You can load data from another file using `require("./data.js")`, where the contents of `data.js` must export your data:

```
module.exports = { ... };
```

[From the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching):

> Multiple calls to require('foo') may not cause the module code to be executed multiple times.

`require` caches the results of executing `data.js`, and serves them from the cache each time they are subsequently requested. Your code simply places data directly inside that cache, without executing an external file.

This **does not** carry any particular advantages over the strategies  above.

If you've got one file, you may as well just reuse the variable `myData` as often as you like - it's not going anywhere. *You don't need to explicitly cache it.*
If you've got multiple files, you should use the `require('foo')` function as intended.

---

## Session-level Persistence

For when you need data to remain available **from one request to another** for some individual user. Note that this is generally weaker than application-level persistence. If the app crashes and restarts between two visits of a single user, the cached data may be lost. If this is problematic, see the final section of this answer.

To achieve this with express, you will need to install the [`express-session`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) package. It's very easy to use. Include it like any other module, tell express to use it as middleware, and you'll find yourself with a persistent `req.session` object which you can store your data inside.

For example:

```
var session = require('express-session');
var app = express();
app.use(session({secret: 'ssshhhhh'}));

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    req.session = myData;
}
```

---

## Global Persistence

For when you need data to become available **even after the application as stopped**. You can pick up where you left off when the application resumes.

This problem is most often solved using an external database. Node passes your data onto some other application (e.g. *MySQL, MongoDB*, ...), and it becomes their responsibility to look after it. When you need the data again, even after a restart, you can simply ask them for it.

In many cases setting up a database just for persistence of data is unnecessary, however. It is easier to simply **write your data to a local file**, which you can trust to remain intact even if your application crashes. In almost every case this will be much faster than using a database.

You can easily do that yourself using the `fs` built-in module, or use a premade solution such as [`node-persist`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-persist). In this case, global persistence is as easy as:

```
var storage = require('node-persist');
storage.initSync();
storage.setItem('myPersistentData', { ... });
console.log(storage.getItem('myPersistentData'));
```

Comment: Nice answer, +1 for the effort to write it. I won't advise node-persist though - much better is a real storage system like Mongo or Redis. But the first part, with in-memory variable is good. I advise the author to use it :)

Comment: Thank you! In truth I haven't much experience with either of those systems. What would be their advantage? I can't imagine they offer a speed advantage compared to just writing to the file-system...

Comment: Oh, especially Redis offers **so much more**! :) It's a kind of a hybrid between memory and file storage - it can save not that used info to drive, but keeps as much as possible in memory. Thus it's incredibly fast and reliable. And it's also **very** scalable - you can run multiple instances and share information between them freaking easily. Having files on system gets a big pain later on. Of course I'm speaking for larger projects than saving a few variables to an Object :)

Comment: @Hephistocles - thanks for your answer 1+! currently two questions :) 1.just to verify require.cache.persist.myData  which I use is not good practice to use?2.assume I take your first option I can imagine module with getters and setters ,this is how you see it also? if yes can you provide simple example please to it?Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you think I've answered the question, please do click the "accept" button! 
I would say that using `require.cache.persist` isn't so much bad practice - it's just pointless. You will get as much persistence by simply defining `var myPersonalCache = {}` and then using it like `myPersonalCache.myData = myData`. Similarly, I think defining getters and setters may be more than you need - you can simply do `module.exports = myData` if you want to access your data between multiple files.

Answer (score 3):

i believe that you want to cache the data on the server side of your application. If this is the case then use can use [node-cache npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache) 
Also, there is one more npm called node-persist that uses the HTML5 localstorage feature's API . [Try it from here](https://github.com/simonlast/node-persist)

Comment: for anyone who finds this later node-cache [might be abandoned](https://github.com/node-cache/node-cache/issues/285)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [node-cache-manager](https://github.com/BryanDonovan/node-cache-manager#single-store) with memory store:

```
var cacheManager = require('cache-manager');
var memoryCache = cacheManager.caching({store: 'memory', max: 100, ttl: 10/*seconds*/});
var ttl = 5;
// Note: callback is optional in set() and del().

memoryCache.set('foo', 'bar', {ttl: ttl}, function(err) {
    if (err) { throw err; }

    memoryCache.get('foo', function(err, result) {
        console.log(result);
        // >> 'bar'
        memoryCache.del('foo', function(err) {});
    });
});
```